# Using ASSERT and EXPECT in GoogleTest

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

While ASSERT_* macros cause termination of test case, EXPECT_* macros continue its evaluation.
I would like to know which is the criteria to decide whether to use one or the other.

Comment: ASSERT_* macros **do not** (necessarily) terminate the test case, please see [Martin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42163715/1969455) for details.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Use `ASSERT` when the condition **must** hold - if it doesn't the test stops right there. Use this when the remainder of the test doesn't have semantic meaning without this condition holding.

Use `EXPECT` when the condition *should* hold, but in cases where it doesn't we can still get value out of continuing the test. (The test will still ultimately fail at the end, though.)

The rule of thumb is: use `EXPECT` by default, unless you *require* something to hold for the remainder of the tests, in which case you should use `ASSERT` for that particular condition.

---

This is echoed within the [primer](https://google.github.io/googletest/primer.html):

> Usually `EXPECT_*` are preferred, as they allow more than one failures to be reported in a test. However, you should use `ASSERT_*` if it doesn't make sense to continue when the assertion in question fails.

Comment: Standard example: before checking contents of container you ASSERT it's size, because it doesn't make sense to check EXPECTations on items that might not even exist (besides, your test would most likely crash if you try to get nth element of empty container).

Comment: It's not about whether or not you want your _program_ to run, it's about whether or not you want the _test suite_ to continue running.  An EXPECT failure should mean that the code you are testing is defective.  An ASSERT failure should mean that the test suite itself is defective or, that the code you are testing is so messed up that there's no point in continuing to try to test it.

Comment: @SolomonSlow 's distinction is key.

Answer (score 29):

Use `EXPECT_` when you

- want to report more than one failure in your test

Use `ASSERT_` when

- it doesn't make sense to continue when the assertion fails

Since `ASSERT_` aborts your function immediately if it fails, possible cleanup code is skipped.
Prefer `EXPECT_` as your default.

Answer (score 10):

In addition to previous answers...

`ASSERT_` does not terminate execution of the test case. It returns from whatever function is was used in. Besides failing the test case, it evaluates to `return;`, and this means that it cannot be used in a function returning something other than `void`. Unless you're fine with the compiler warning, that is.

`EXPECT_` fails the test case but does not `return;`, so it can be used inside functions of any return type.

Answer (score 0):

ASSERT_*:

- when it fails, won't check the remaining conditions.

EXPECT_*:

- when it is failed, it still checks the remaining conditions.