# Assertion testing a void function

Tags: c++, unit-testing, methods, struct, assert

I am writing a code with multiple void methods within a class, I am tasked with testing all of my methods using the `assert` from the c++ header `<cassert>`.  Here is one of my methods, that goes through the array in the class and trims the leading and trailing blank spaces. How would I write a function to test this method using `assert`? I am confused because there is no return value.

```
void trim_all() {
    // Iterate through all strings
    for (int i = 0; i < strSize; i++) {
        // Initialize variables
        int begin = 0;
        int end = arr[i].size() - 1;
        // While loops to check how many spaces in front and back
        while (begin < arr[i].size() && arr[i][begin] == ' ') {
            begin++;
        }
        while (end >= 0 && arr[i][end] == ' ') {
            end--;
        }
        // Update string to trimmed version
        arr[i] = arr[i].substr(begin, end - begin + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: `assert` is not designed for unit-testing -- it is designed for validating assumptions at runtime to catch places where you screwed up.  If I was to add assertions to this code example, one of the first ones I consider might be `assert(!arr[i].empty());` because `arr[i].size() - 1` will underflow an unsigned value if the size is zero.  That could be bad.  For actual unit-testing, you would set up your object, call the function, and then test the object state afterwards against an expected state.  It's quite different from assertions.

Comment: Are you actually trying to unit test the code, or are you trying to add pre and post conditions, loop invariants, etc?

Answer (score 2):

based on the code's implementation,
you can check a result to fit with what the trim_all function do
in your case the function delete all space at begin and end or the arr var.
ex:
input :

```
arr = "   abc  d  "
trim_all();
assert(arr == "abc  d");
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with paddy, `assert` is not a good fit here - it will terminate your program on the first failure.

However, all test frameworks have their version of assertion, that would report the failure (optionally with details) and keep going.

For that later case, the assertion is trivial: iterate through your `arr` and make sure that each string doesn't begin or end with a space.

See this: [Using ASSERT and EXPECT in GoogleTest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565299/using-assert-and-expect-in-googletest)

Answer (score 1):

The function has side-effects. You're supposed to test that the side-effects are what they are supposed to be. This applies to all functions that have side-effects; not only those that return `void`. The function modifies elements of `arr`.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the comments and answers explain that the use of `assert` is not a good choice for writing test code - which is true.  However, since you write

> I am tasked with testing all of my methods using the assert from the c++ header .

it sounds a bit as if this was an exercise for some kind of programming or testing course.  In that case, I take it that either at some later point in your course you will be introduced to some better suited testing framework, or that testing is not meant to be covered thoroughly during your course and for that reason the introduction of a testing framework is considered too time consuming.

Whatever the reason, you can actually start writing tests with the help of `assert`, using `assert` as a poor man's testing framework, as @long-kl has shown in his answer (but without giving more explanation).

`assert(<condition>);` will evaluate the condition, and, if the condition evaluates to some true value, the execution of your program will simply continue with the next statement.  Otherwise, the program will terminate.

Thus, you can use `assert` for the verification of a test result, namely by writing the condition to check if the actual result of some computation matches the expected result, as the following example test cases (by far not exhaustive) show:

```
// Test case: Array claimed to be empty is not touched
arr = { " a " };
strSize = 0;
trim_all();
assert(arr[0] == " a ");  // expected value is " a ", actual is arr[0]
// Only if the test passes, we reach the following line:
cout << "Passed: Array claimed to be empty is not touched\n";

// Test case: Empty string remains untouched
arr = { "" };
strSize = 1;
trim_all();
assert(arr[0] == "");
cout << "Passed: Empty string remains untouched\n";

// Test case: Blank-only string becomes empty string
arr = { "   " };
strSize = 1;
trim_all();
assert(arr[0] == "");
cout << "Passed: Blank-only string becomes empty string\n";

// Test case: Front blanks get trimmed
arr = { "   abc" };
strSize = 1;
trim_all();
assert(arr[0] == "abc");
cout << "Passed: Front blanks get trimmed\n";

// further test cases...
```

In case of a passing test, the program will continue with the next test.  In contrast, if a test fails, that is, the condition evaluates to some false value, the program will terminate at that point with some error message.  Consequently, after a failing test no further tests will be executed.

Thus, the reason that `assert` has no return value is that a true condition means to continue executing, and a false condition means terminating.